# Test all git commits in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I've just set up Jenkins, which should run tests on an existing project that is maintained in git.

Now, I'd like to run my test on all existing revisions, rather than just the newest one. The tests I'm running generate lots of statistics (e.g. FPGA resource usage) that are interesting to compare between individual commits. As typical workflows can introduce many commits atomically, the commits introduced since the last run should be tested as well, and historic data added to get a better overview of project history.

Quick googling found lots of people with the same problem, but no real solutions.

I've found the [Git Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin), which is slightly underdocumented.

Is there an easy way to configure such a setup?

Comment: Can you expand on why you want to run your test against old revisions ?  A continuous integration system is usually intended to test new revisions as soon as they are committed.

Comment: @gareth_bowles, I've extended the question.

Comment: I configured Jenkins to give commit test status. Indeed I wish I could test all my commit even if commit are made when test of another commit are running.

Comment: why not use script to do the loop for all your interesting git commit and compare the result

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer...
I'd be inclined to look at what commits you're getting in each push (I assume each push corresponds to a build on Jenkins for you).
If your developers use commits locally on steps in building that maybe aren't designed for wider consumption, but to enable roll backs of tricky steps etc, you could get an awful lot of build/test cycles to run, a lot which fail. Could this also make your stats too noisy to use?
Can you get fewer commits in each atom by getting people to push more often? Testing more often and smaller deltas in the code strike me as a good thing.

Comment: Pushing more often is difficult, as lots of work is done offline, and commits are often rewritten while being polished.